# Using multiple @Html.ValidationMessageFor() helpers with single model property

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Foo)` to display unobtrusive validation messages, but when I use it more than once in my View, only one validation message displays.

Here's an example of how I'm using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Foo, true, new { @id = "FooTrue" })
<label for="FooTrue">Yes</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Foo, false, new { @id = "FooFalse" })
<label for="FooFalse">No</label>

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Foo)
```

It looks like the `<span>` elements that `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Foo)` compiles into have fixed `id` attributes:

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Foo" data-valmsg-replace="true">
    <span id="Foo-error" class="">
        Please select an option.
    </span>
</span>
```

Explicitly defining a unique id attribute on my duplicate `ValidationMessageFor` didn't work:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Foo, "Please select an option", new { @id = "DuplicateValidationMessage" })
```

Is there any way to use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Foo)` multiple times in my View?

Also, is a solution possible with Javascript, or will this mess with the jQuery unobtrusive validation plugin?

Comment: I did't get what you are trying to do here! you want to display validation message for the same Model property twice? As per my understanding that property will have one value at a time and that value will be validated and will show a message, dont get the purpose of having 2 different validations for the same Model property.,,  can you put the html with both your validators?

Comment: Even if you do get it to show twice, they will both just show the same exact message (which doesn't seem very useful from a user's perspective)

Comment: @Aram I know it sounds weird, but yeah, this is exactly what I'm trying to do.  It's for a form with duplicate questions that all reference to the same ViewModel property, and whose radio button values are bound together with KnockoutJS.

Comment: If you have 'duplicate' questions, then your questions should be  a collection and the html generated in a `for` loop so that each element has a unique `name` and `id` attribute which will allow you to use `ValidationMessageFor` on each one.